# Removing everything from a text file except first line

Tags: c#, .net

How can I remove everything from a text file except for the first line?

I tried:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + "/resource.rpf" + "/" + "__resource.lua");
foreach (var item in lines.Take(1));
```

but doesn't work like I wanted.

Comment: Are you sure the file is actually multiple lines and not just wrapped? That or `lines[0]` should work.

Comment: _doesn't work_ means? Exception or wrong output. Can you add input and desired output to the question?

Comment: The string is a multiple line text. Doesn't work I meant doesn't output what I wanted.

Comment: Why do you need a loop if it is only one line? You can simply use `lines[0]`.

Comment: Do you mean that you wanted to overwrite the file to have only the first line of the content?

Comment: I wanted to have the first line of a certain string + a another string. it worked  using the choosed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using File.ReadAllLines

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path + "/resource.rpf" + "/" + "__resource.lua");        
string firstLine = lines[0];
```

### Using Stream Reader (best)

The best solution would be to only read in the first line to begin with:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path" + "/resource.rpf" + "/" + "__resource.lua"))
{
    string firstLine = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`lines` is a string array, so you can simply use:

```
lines[0]
```

But it is better to only read the first line unless you want the other lines in some other parts of your code.